# gradle 7.1 + java 15 - build.gradle trubbleshooting

Tags: java, gradle, jar

just need some quick help from an experienced gradle pro.
Im pretty new in the subject, till today i only used gradle (didnt really do more than ./gradlew build) and that even on 4.3.
For a private project i wanted to include a library in my build.gradle.
it builds and all, but when i want to start the jar with java -jar it cant find classes of the included library (NoClassDefFoundError).

I cant get my mind on whats wrong, so im thankfull for every help i can get.

This is my build.gradle so far

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
apply plugin:'java'
apply plugin: 'java-library'
group 'org.example'
version '1.0'

dependencies {
    //local file
    implementation(files('../../Library/TwitchIRC-1.0.jar'))
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'SensenChatbot.Bot',
                'Class-Path': configurations.runtimeClasspath.files.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')
        )
    }
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your project depends on some external library (`TwitchIRC-1.0.jar`). When You run jar file from command line You need to add it to classpath via `-cp` parameter:

```
java -cp /path/to/your/jar/Application.jar;/path/to/Library/TwitchIRC-1.0.jar org.example.Main
```

Notice than You don't specify `-jar` param, instead You need to add both jars to classpath and specify Main class to be run.

Another way is to build fatJar (https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar), which will include application with all it's dependencies.